# How to duplicate a form in Visual Basic 2010 in same project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have a question on how to make another WindowsForm just like an existing WindowsForm that I created earlier ?
I have a WindowsForm that has a lot of properties and buttons and stuff like that and I have to create 12 more of that form with just small modifications but I don't seem like to be able to find a way to do it every single way I tried gets me a lot of errors, I'm using Visual Basic Express 2010

Comment: @MitchWheat this is what happens when I copy. paste .. http://i.imgur.com/ZueBt1W.png

Comment: Please do not add [RESOLVED] to your question title. Instead, mark the response that resolved it as an answer.

Comment: @ElGavilan sorry didn't know that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after messing around with my project files I finally duplicated the form that I wanted to and this is how I did it, after going to the project directory I found the WindowsForm file for example the Form's name was "Unknown1.vb" in Visual Basic 2010 where I created it, In the project's directory there were 3 files created for that WindowsForm they were " Login.vb " + "Login.resx" and "Login.Designer.vb" and I copied those 3 files and renamed every "Login" with "Login2" and then opened "Login2.vb" and "Login2.Designer.vb" with Wordpad and replaced every "Login" with "Login2" and saved them, and then I selected "Add an existing file" to my project and I selected the modified "Login2.vb" file and it worked like a charm ! 
I created 12 WindowsForms using this .

Here are the steps with pictures :
First things first we go to the projects directory and then :
Here are all the steps : https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7ChY.jpg

That is it hope this answer helps others that are looking for a way to duplicate WindowsForms.